# how to select objects feom 2d sheets using window selection

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm new to Autodesk forging, I'm wondering if I can select elements in 2d plans using a window selection extension.
i've seen some blogs and i know that it's possible on 3d models

Answer (score 1):

Started from [v7.32](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/#id16), Forge Viewer has the native window selection extension called `Autodesk.BoxSelection`. It supports both 2D and 3D views, but its button is hidden by default. You can add it back with the following code snippet.

```js
viewer.addEventListener(
      Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT,
      (event) => {
        if(event.extensionId != 'Autodesk.BoxSelection') return;

        var viewer = event.target;
        var boxSelExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.BoxSelection');
        boxSelExt.addToolbarButton(true); //!<<< Show the toolbar button for this extension
      });
```

**Note.** This code snippet should be added before loading the model.

[image]